# How to do restful search in Apache Sling

Tags: sling

i am evaluating Apache Sling as a potential backend CMS.  I like how easy it is to push / get new content via rest.  However, I also need to be able to search the content via REST.  I compiled all the source code and am running their standalone jar.  There are like 100 bundles installed, but I can't find a single rest query.

Some old documentation says you can do /content/mynode.query.json?

But this is not working, and there is no help on whether its supported or not.  Honestly the only search option I found was in the console via /.explore.search.html/ which returns web pages.

How can you do restful search using sling?

Answer (score 3):

The JsonQueryServlet, which provides an HTTP search interface was moved to a separate bundle as part of [SLING-2226](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SLING-2226). See that issue's page for how to use it, and there's a related blog post at http://in-the-sling.blogspot.ch/2008/09/how-to-use-json-query-servlet.html